# Docker image only works on one Fedora server?

Tags: fedora, docker

I have two groups of servers, a development server running a docker repo (F22 Server) and a few production servers running far less (F22 cloud/atomic) in Hyper-V. I have built an image for the UniFi wireless controller that works (and works well) on the development server, but when attempting to run it on the cloud/atomic VMs the memory usage will only reach 150MB (should be 300MB) and mongoDB does not start inside the container (using docker top ).

I have verified that the image ID and timestamp are exactly the same, and that the run command is identical. I even tried running with --net=host and --privileged=true on the production VMs instead of exposing the ports and still mongoDB will not start. Docker logs  produces nothing, and the attached terminal is also silent. In addition, both "machines" are running Docker 1.6. Docker settings are default, aside from adding implicit trust for the local FQDN of the repository on the dev server. The cloud/atomic hosts will run all my other containers except this one.

Comment: UPDATE: looking in /var/log/unifi/mongod.log I'm seeing that the unifi controller's embedded mongod is (repeatedly) refusing to start because it is demanding 3GB free space and being told there is not enough ... yet this runs with the same command on the development server? Both servers have (mostly empty) 64GB VHDs ... Is there a docker config option to change here?

Comment: How is storage configured on the working host versus the non-working host? See `/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage`

Comment: A-ha. The working server has nothing there (defaults) and the non-working server has --storage-opt dm.fs=xfs --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/fedora-docker--pool

I tried deleting the contents of the file but after that (and restarting) I can't run containers at all, so Fedora Atomic which is "optimized for docker in production" has some configuration / scripting voodoo that interferes here.

Comment: Time to restore the contents of that file. The reason for looking at it is to _find out what storage is being used_ so that you can determine if it is actually full or not.

Comment: Looks to be a logical volume that is 58.4GB in size and 2% full :\

Going to try marking that subdirectory as a volume in docker and see what happens.

Comment: fdisk -l shows a 10GB drive when the container is running, that's more than 3 GB ...

Comment: It's a devicemapper thinpool, which is quite different. I have one in prod and don't want to mess with it; I'll bring up my test system later and figure out the right commands to find out the real space usage.

Comment: Just P.S. don't drive yourself crazy on my account, I just deleted the Atomic VMs in favor of putting F22 Server Minimal into production and it runs the problem container fine, even though its docker image/container storage solution is "not for production."

Still interested in why exactly F22 Atomic can't run mongodb for curiosity's sake, of course.

Comment: Heh. I need to do it anyway for other reasons, it just wasn't very high on the to-do list.